# How to access individual values from an NSArray?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Trying to iterate through an array of values coming in from a push notification.

This is what the object in push notification object would look like:

`"storyids": [12345, 12346, 12347, 12348]`

At which, I can intercept this value in my ios app delegate, as such:

`storyIds = aps.ObjectForKey(new NSString("storyids")) as NSArray;`

But now I am having trouble iterating through this collection (which I want to essentially convert to a C# collection)

This is what I've tried:

```
for (nuint i = 0; i < storyIds.Count; i++)
{
    var j = storyIds.ValueAt(i);
}
```

Which gives me a weird number and not the value at that particular index. I can't seem to find any method of NSArray to get the value from the array at a particular index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `storyIds.GetItem<NSString> (0)` or `NSString.FromHandle (storyIds.ValueAt (0))`.